# Problems token expires on Google API

Tags: php, google-api, access-token

Good morning to all, use google-api-client to PHP for authentication of users, but at some time expires 'acces token' and calls to authenticate user again, anyone know to set or I file modified to last longer the token certainly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and in my case I used a method called isAccessTokenExpired(), then make an authenticate request again

```
if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
      googleClient->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

if (googleClient->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $authUrl = googleClient->createAuthUrl();
    header("Location:$authUrl");
}
```

hope it helps :).

Comment: You will have to call the methods in your current Google_Client object, for me in this example was `googleClient = new Google_Client()`